# Why change the network speed for the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, network-programming

Using the command prompt, terminal, or shell we can adjust the network speed of our emulator. Are there any practical uses to doing so?

Comment: So that you can test your app on varying speed.

Comment: For example imitate lag.

Comment: okay and? People's speed can be really broad, I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful while testing for older devices.

If you want to see how your application will respond to lower network connectivity or slower devices, it helps to be able to simulate that.

If you are not concerned about that for your application as there is not a time constraint on your content, then there is no need to do so.